# BASH execute binary file and read/modify variables

Tags: bash, shell-script

I used to do this:

```
declare -g var='value'
. ~script.sh sub
```

and my `var` was available to read and modify from within my sub.

Now I have a binary instead of `script.sh` and I want the same functionality.
Of course, now I cannot do `. ~/script.bin sub` because bash `'cannot execute binary file'`

Instead I have to :

```
declare -g var='value'
~/script.bin sub
```

How do I get  `~/script.bin sub` to read/modify my `var`?

I tried also:
`declare -gx var='value'` and `export var='value'` but no cookie.

Comment: Is the binary fixed? or can you modify its source and recompile? If you can, see answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1376604/432690).

Comment: Child processes don't modify the environment of their parent.  The design is this way so that child processes (such as binary executables) can't mess up the parents environment.  Instead, rewrite the binary so that it returns the value in some way.  For example, `var=$(script.bin bin)`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It is my own binary using SHC, so I can modify it.

Comment: @John1024 I cannot read the var

Comment: maybe I can use shared memory? I have not checked that.

Comment: @conanDrum By using `declare -a`, `var` is declared  to be an _array_ but assigned it to a single value.  Last I checked, arrays [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5564589/3030305) be exported to child processes.  Since you're only assigning a single value, do you really need the array?

Comment: no I do not need an array. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to run `unset var` and then `declare -gx var='value'`.  After that is done, your binary should be able to see the variable and to modify its local copy.  You'll still need to do something, such as `var=$(script.bin bin)`, to return an updated value.

Comment: @John1024 Problem is I have 10 variables that this script used to be able to access as global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with shared memory and it maybe a good and easy option.

In my `~/script.bin sub` I now have:

```
sub() {
shmvar="/dev/shm/var"
echo "sub var: " && cat "${shmvar}"  # show the imported var
echo "new value" > "$shmvar"         # modify the var
return 0
}
```

whilst in the main script I have:

```
var='old value'
shmvar="/dev/shm/colBlack"    # shm var address
echo "$var" > "$shmvar"       # populate shmvar with var
~/scirpt.bin sub              # call my binary sub
echo "new var: " && cat "${shmvar}"  # check the modified var
```

output:

```
sub var:
old value
new var:
new value
```